# MKLocalSearch result won't return more than one match

Tags: ios, swift

I'm currently trying to implement a Map connected with a search function. For the overlay containing the table view, I've decided to go for a library called [FloatingPanel](https://github.com/SCENEE/FloatingPanel). Anyways, this shouldn't be of importance, since it shouldn't affect the code for the search bar etc.

To search for matching results I execute `MKLocalSearch.Request` every time the text changes inside of the search bar. It works, but the matching results are kind of weird - **most of the time the function only returns one matching item, even though there should be more. Additionally sometime there are no matches for some villages, but for their gym.**

What I want is to display several suggestions as soon as the user start typing. For example if he starts typing "Los", I want the function to already return a suggestion: "Los Angeles" and many more - just like in the actual Apple Map app.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import FloatingPanel

class MapViewController: UIViewController, FloatingPanelControllerDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate  {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    var fpc: FloatingPanelController!
    var searchVC: BottomSheetViewController!

    var resultSearchController:UISearchController? = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SearchPanel") as! BottomSheetViewController
        vc.mapView = mapView

        fpc = FloatingPanelController()
        fpc.delegate = self

        fpc.surfaceView.backgroundColor = .clear
        fpc.surfaceView.cornerRadius = 9.0
        fpc.surfaceView.shadowHidden = false

        searchVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SearchPanel") as? BottomSheetViewController

        fpc.set(contentViewController: searchVC)
        fpc.track(scrollView: searchVC.tableView)

        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.requestLocation()

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        fpc.addPanel(toParent: self, animated: true)

        searchVC.searchBar.delegate = self
    }

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        guard let mapView = mapView,
            let searchBarText = searchVC.searchBar.text else { return }
        let request = MKLocalSearch.Request()
        request.naturalLanguageQuery = searchBarText
        request.region = mapView.region
        let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
        search.start { response, _ in
            guard let response = response else {
                return
            }
            self.searchVC.matchingItems = response.mapItems
            self.searchVC.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
        searchBar.showsCancelButton  = false
        searchVC.hideHeader()
        fpc.move(to: .half, animated: true)
    }

    func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
        searchVC.showHeader()
        searchVC.tableView.alpha = 1.0
        fpc.move(to: .full, animated: true)
    }

    func floatingPanelDidMove(_ vc: FloatingPanelController) {
        let y = vc.surfaceView.frame.origin.y
        let tipY = vc.originYOfSurface(for: .tip)
        if y > tipY - 44.0 {
            let progress = max(0.0, min((tipY  - y) / 44.0, 1.0))
            self.searchVC.tableView.alpha = progress
        }
    }

    func floatingPanelWillBeginDragging(_ vc: FloatingPanelController) {
        if vc.position == .full {
            searchVC.searchBar.showsCancelButton = false
            searchVC.searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
        }
    }

    func floatingPanelDidEndDragging(_ vc: FloatingPanelController, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetPosition: FloatingPanelPosition) {
        if targetPosition != .full {
            searchVC.hideHeader()
        }

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25,
                       delay: 0.0,
                       options: .allowUserInteraction,
                       animations: {
                        if targetPosition == .tip {
                            self.searchVC.tableView.alpha = 0.0
                        } else {
                            self.searchVC.tableView.alpha = 1.0
                        }
        }, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

The data is being displayed in a table view inside of another view controller:

```
class BottomSheetViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    @IBOutlet weak var visualEffectView: UIVisualEffectView!

    var matchingItems: [MKMapItem] = []
    var mapView: MKMapView? = nil



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        searchBar.placeholder = "Search for a place or address"
        let textField = searchBar.value(forKey: "_searchField") as! UITextField
        textField.font = UIFont(name: textField.font!.fontName, size: 15.0)

    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        if #available(iOS 10, *) {
            visualEffectView.layer.cornerRadius = 9.0
            visualEffectView.clipsToBounds = true
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return matchingItems.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! SearchCell
        let selectedItem = matchingItems[indexPath.row].placemark

        cell.titleLabel.text = selectedItem.name

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)
    }

}
```

SearchCell:

```
class SearchCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!

}
```

Comment: It's already old but I'm currently on the same problem as you, did you find a solution to that?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Apple designed `MKLocalSearch` so it should be used on the results of `MKLocalSearchCompleter`. Run `MKLocalSearchCompleter` first, let the user select the result they need and then run `MKLocalSearch` with selected `MKLocalSearchCompletion` as argument. In this scheme it makes perfect sense why `MKLocalSearch` returns only one result, because the user already saw all possible variants.

For example, if you search *Moscow* with `MKLocalSearchCompleter` it will return you not only an obvious *Moscow, Russia*, but also a dozen of towns in the US with same name. But if you make the same search with `MKLocalSearch` it will only returns you the first match.